# Viewing.Extension.Markup3D in Autodesk Forge viewer

Tags: javascript, .net, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

Is there any example of how to add a Viewing.Extension.Markup3D extension in .NET Core project with vanilla JavaScript?

I saw an example here https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-rcdb.nodejs but this is done in react.js.

How can I register this extension in forge viewer with plain JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are talking about this extension: [Viewing.Extension.Markup3D in Autodesk Forge viewer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70437342/viewing-extension-markup3d-in-autodesk-forge-viewer) 
It is indeed written in a way to make it usable from a React app. You would have to get rid of all the React-specific things in it to load it from a plain JavaScript app.

There is a newer sample that is using plain JavaScript you could have a look at: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/3d-markup-icons-and-info-card

Comment: Hi Adam, thank you for answering, I was thinking on this markup3d extension that I found here: https://forge-rcdb.autodesk.io/database?id=583ec7efebfb320e3cef26a5 
It's not the same as this one https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/3d-markup-icons-and-info-card or am I missing something?

Comment: The first link I provided was wrong I meant to use this https://adndevblog.typepad.com/cloud_and_mobile/2016/04/markup3d-sample-for-view-data-api.html, which is written to be used from a React app. This other 3d markup (https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/3d-markup-icons-and-info-card) is not the same but provides similar functionality and it's not React specific.